# How to get full website url screen shot in php

Tags: php, webpage-screenshot

How can I get the full page of a website in image format ?

Til now I am doing like this :

```
<?php
$siteURL = "https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/using-history";
$googlePagespeedData = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=$siteURL&screenshot=true");//decode json data
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode($googlePagespeedData, true);//screenshot data
$screenshot = $googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data'];
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'),array('/','+'),$screenshot); //display screenshot image
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$screenshot."' />";
?>
```

**To get the response please check:**
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/using-history&screenshot=true

Here I am not getting the full image of the website.

How can I get the full website in image ?

Comment: what's the output of var_dump($googlePagespeedData) ?

Comment: currnt output ?

Comment: Use phantomjs, casperjs or selenium to do what you want.

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: Thanks all for your time.. please hit this url you will get the response... As the response is too large I have not uploaded it .

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/using-history&screenshot=true